# Looping error message

Tags: java, input, for-loop

```
  String inputRules = JOptionPane.showInputDialog
  (
  "Enter your rules. \n" +
  "In the form: a=x"
  );

    boolean gotGoodRuleInput = false;

    while (!gotGoodRuleInput)
    {
      gotGoodRuleInput = true;   

      char a = inputRules.charAt(0);

      for (int i= 2; i<inputRules.length(); i++)
      {
      char x = inputRules.charAt(i);
      if (a == x)
      {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog
        ( 
          null,
          "a can not equal x",
          "Error",
          JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE
        );
        gotGoodRuleInput = false;
       }
      }
    }
```

Hello Im trying to check the users input and if the input at x is equal to a then it will give the error dialog box. The issue I'm having is that the error dialog box "a can not equal x" keeps coming up over and over and doesn't close when hitting ok. I assume it has to do with the for loop but I can't figure it out.

Comment: I don't see the point of what you are doing. I believe a better way of doing this would be using the split method within the String class to seperate the before the '=' sign part and the after the '=' sign part.

Comment: hmm I didn't know about this I think it does work better thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your setting of `inputRules` is outside the loop, so once you get the error condition you'll never get out of it.

Answer (score 1):

Problem in logic, in your logic
look

```
while (!gotGoodRuleInput)
    {
```

...

and if error

```
gotGoodRuleInput = false;
```

What is happening:

1. check while conditon
2. set up while condition to false
3. read a
4. loop through all input values
5. check codition
6. show dialog
7. if above condition true, set up while condition to true
8. go to the first step

Answer (score 0):

And like John said, inputRules is outside the loop so nothing will ever change. Not sure if this is what you were trying to accomplish but if you can replace the loop all together with this.

```
String[] input = inputRules.split("=");
if (input[0].equals(intput[1])) {
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog
    ( 
        null,
        "a equals x"
    );
    gotGoodRuleInput = true;
} else {
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog
    ( 
        null,
        "a can not equal x",
        "Error",
        JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE
    );
    gotGoodRuleInput = false;
}
```

Comment: Thanks I didn't know about splitting but it seems very useful